# Comparison between Arch Linux and Tiny Core

Tags: arch-linux, tinycore

What is the difference between Arch Linux distro and Tiny Core distro? I have yet to find a website which compares them.

Answer (score 3):

There is not ”a difference”, there are almost too many to list. But basically:

- Arch Linux is what you make it. Once installed, you are left with a minimal GNU/Linux system that you can cofigure however you want.
- Whereas with Tiny Core, you boot into a predefined file manager and desktop (FLTK/FLWM) in a BusyBox environment.

Honestly, I would say that the only things that are similar between the two is that they have their own package managers, and that they are not based on any other distributions (except for ”dCore“ - based on Debian).

I strongly urge you to read the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux) and the [Tiny Core wiki](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:getting_started).